# Retry on redis connection failure

Tags: go, redis

Wondering why redigo decided not to export the errorConn type, which would allow applications to have specific error handling for connection failures. As implemented, applications have to handle these as generic errors.

For example, our application generally doesn't care if a single PUT fails, but if the issue is a redis connection failure or redis pool being exhausted, moving on to the next PUT (especially if it requires opening a new connection) is a bad idea. We should stop and retry (with exponential backoff) until the connection comes back.

[Code](https://github.com/gomodule/redigo/blob/72af8129e040d6f962772a8c582e5e9f22085788/redis/pool.go#L247-L250) example where redigo returns a generic error if the connection pool is exhausted

Comment: Your post doesn't seem to include a question, but you seem to be asking about a design decision in redigo, which you'd have to ask the author.

Comment: Use [Conn.Err()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Conn.Err) to detect an unusable connection. I am not sure what you mean by a "generic error", but the linked code returns the specific error `redis.ErrPoolExhausted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines of code in your link return two values of the respective types: `(Conn, error)`.

```golang
if !p.Wait && p.MaxActive > 0 && p.active >= p.MaxActive {
    p.mu.Unlock()
    return errorConn{ErrPoolExhausted}, ErrPoolExhausted
}
```

The type `Conn` is an interface with an `Err` method.

```golang
// Err returns a non-nil value when the connection is not usable.
Err() error
```

So to obtain the underlying error, you can either:

- call the `Err` method on the first return value; or
- check the second `error` return value.

As a side note, the recommended way to compare errors is by using `errors.Is` and/or `errors.As` from the standard library [`errors`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors) package.

Comment: Thank you. Combining this answer with one of the comments, I found that I can use errors.Is to check if the err returned is redis.ErrPoolExhausted. My confusion was around how ErrPoolExhausted is set equal to a "generic error," i.e., errors.New("error message"), not realizing that the capital letter meant that the error type was exported and I could reference it directly in my app.